# Print line have special format and amount of comma

Tags: awk

This is my sample :

```
6751176513,ahggasda,3453453,hgdahgsd,hgfhgfhg,,
,,

ajhgdha | sajhsgdahj|sdahgdhjaghjsd
6751176513,ahggasda,gdfgdf,2015-10-20 05:15:25,sdfsd,,
```

I need to print the lines that have this criteria:

1. Amount of commmas = 6
2. the second field must have value (not NULL)
3. the fourth field must have timestamp format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS)

I need to use "AWK" in this case.

Comment: Just to make sure the obvious: your fields are separated by commas? (One of your sample lines has `|`, which I could see people using as separators.)

Comment: ya but i need the comma lines only .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a combination of awk and grep.

```
awk -F"," ' { 
       if ( $2 != "" && $4 ~ /[[:digit:]]{4}(-[[:digit:]]{2}){2} [[:digit:]]{2}(:[[:digit:]]{2}){2}/ ) print
} ' <file> | grep '.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*'
```

EDIT: A Pure awk alternative. Thanks to @Archemar for pointing it out.

```
awk -F"," ' {
       if ( NF == 7 && $2 != "" && $4 ~ /[[:digit:]]{4}(-[[:digit:]]{2}){2} [[:digit:]]{2}(:[[:digit:]]{2}){2}/ ) print
} ' <file>
```

Comment: thank you .. it works . do u have any full manual for the AWK programming

Comment: if you mind, could you please explan your code for me and any other beginner .

Comment: @AhmedSamir , the `-F` is used to denote the the field separator, in this case comma. Then you pass the commands which in this is just an `if` statement where we check if the second field is not blank and if the fourth field matches the pattern (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS) and if so print the matching line. In the end we pipe the output to grep to print only those lines which have 6 commas.

Comment: could you please recommand AWK manual  to learn from it

Comment: @AhmedSamir The following links could be helpful if you'd like to start from the basics - http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AWK.

Comment: @rahul grep can be avoided using NF == 7 (6 commas, 7 field) as a pattern.

Comment: @Archemar thanks. I'll include that as a pure awk answer as well.

Comment: when i try to made some fack timestamps .. the AWK fail to understand the format this is the out put ,, this is wronge 
2015-10-20.05:15:25   --- > wronge   
2015-2015-03-22.19:02:40  ------- wronge  
2015-03-22 19:02:40  --  right
thank you

Comment: @AhmedSamir Yes. It's designed to work with that particular format(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS). If you'd like it to match other formats as well, the regex pattern needs to be modified. Why would you need other patterns? This is the standard pattern. Well if you really like for it to handle other patterns, then you need to list the possible patterns and come up with a regex for it.

Comment: first of all thank yu for your fast reply .. yes, you t right but the problem is the three outputs is not full right there are two values wronge, when i try to execute the AWK the three values shown and we need just 1 only .

Answer (score 2):

You'd do better to just use `grep`. I know a regexp like that can seem daunting, but it gets better if you just take a step back.

```
__=[^,]* d=[0-9][0-9] y=$d$d m=$d

grep "^$__,${__%?}$__,$__,$y-$m-$d $d:$d:$d,$__,$__,$__$\
" <<\IN
6751176513,ahggasda,3453453,hgdahgsd,hgfhgfhg,,
,,

ajhgdha | sajhsgdahj|sdahgdhjaghjsd
6751176513,ahggasda,gdfgdf,2015-10-20 05:15:25,sdfsd,,
IN
```

See? Its not all that bad - and it even makes some sense. This is one thing BREs *(basic regular expressions)* are very good for: easy higher level abstraction.

The above prints.

```
6751176513,ahggasda,gdfgdf,2015-10-20 05:15:25,sdfsd,,
```

Comment: am trying but not working .. thank you for help